# Remove leading zeroes in Lua string

Tags: scripting, lua, numbers, string-formatting

I have number string of 6 digits but sometimes I become number with leading zeroes, how can I simple and handily remove that leading zeroes in Lua?

Answer (score 1):

You can strip leading zeros with string operations. e.g.:

```
x = x:match("0*(%d+)")
```

Comment: Gives me nil on empty string "". Unexpected behavior, not good.

Answer (score 0):

Done... It was simple...

```
join = string.format("%u", join);
```

Comment: That involves an implicit coercion string=>number and back again.

Comment: This does not work for really big numbers

Answer (score 0):

This one appears to work also for empty strings, string without leading zeros, etc:

```lua
x = string.gsub(x, '0*', '', 1)
```

or

```lua
x = x:gsub('0*', '', 1)
```

Comment: What does the last argument `1` mean?